# Gerar vários registros no MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

No *MySQL* tenho duas tabelas:

- CLIENTES

  ```
  | codigo-cliente | nome | grupo | valor |
  |----------------|------|-------|-------|
  ```
- FINANCEIRO

  ```
  | codigo-cliente | codigo-boleto | grupo | valor |
  |----------------|---------------|-------|-------|
  ```

Na página de gerar boletos, tenho um campo onde seleciono para qual grupo de clientes quero gerar os boletos.

Ao clicar para gerar, preciso que o sistema gere na tabela FINANCEIRO um boleto para cada cliente da tabela CLIENTE que faça parte do grupo selecionado.

**Exemplo:**

Selecionei o grupo 10 e mandei gerar

Tabela CLIENTES

```
| codigo-cliente | nome   | grupo | valor |
|----------------|--------|-------|-------|
| 1              | teste1 | 10    | 100   |
| 2              | teste2 | 12    | 60    |
| 3              | teste3 | 10    | 30    |
```

Na tabela FINANCEIRO vai registrar um boleto para cada cliente que esteja no grupo 10.

Tabela FINANCEIRO

```
| codigo-cliente | codigo-boleto | grupo | valor |
|----------------|---------------|-------|-------|
| 1              | 200           | 10    | 100   |
| 3              | 201           | 10    | 30    |
```

Comment: Se possível poste o código que você já tentou.

Comment: Você não informou de onde vem a informação para o "codigo-boleto"

Comment: Pagotti, o "codigo-boleto" é gerado automaticamente pelo MySQL.

Comment: Valdeir Psr, não consegui encontrar a logica ideal, por isto nao tenho o codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como temos o post que recebemos do formulário, com o `grupo`, faremos o seguinte:

```
// Seleciono tudo que envolve o grupo = 10.
$this->db->where('grupo', $this->input->post('grupo'));
$consulta = $this->db->get('clientes')->result();

// Com base nisso, faço o laço de repetição, para que eu insira no banco de dados, todos os boletos gerados com grupo = 10
foreach($consulta as $valor){
    $dados['codigo-boleto'] = '200';
    $dados['grupo'] = $valor->grupo;
    $dados['codigo-cliente'] = $valor->codigo-cliente;
    $dados['valor'] = '100'; 
    $this->db->insert('financeiro', $dados);
}
```

Dessa forma você insere todos os boletos, de acordo com o grupo selecionado. Porém, há de se observar que você não possui nenhum informativo vindo via post, do valor e nem do codigo do boleto.

Comment: Andre, infelizmente não funcionou.
Não sei se fiz algo errado alem do que me passou...vou atualizar a pergunta com o codigo utilizado;

Answer (score 0):

Segue o codigo utilizado:

**VIEW**
Possui o formulário e o código ajax:

```
<script>
$("#frmCobrancas").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var base_url = "<?php echo base_url() ?>";

    $.ajax({
        url : base_url+'financeiro/gerar_cobrancas',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            'rota_cobranca': $('#cRotacobranca').val(),
            'data_emissao': $('#cDataemissao').val(),
            'mes_referencia': $('#cMesreferencia').val(),
            'data_vencimento': $('#cDatavencimento').val()

        },success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }

    });
});
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function gerar_cobrancas() {
    if ($this->input->post('rota_cobranca') == ""){
        echo 0;
    }else{

        $data = array(
            'rota_cobranca'     => $this->input->post('rota_cobranca'),
            'data_emissao'      => FormatarDataUS($this->input->post('data_emissao')),
            'mes_referencia'    => FormatarDataUS($this->input->post('mes_referencia')),
            'data_vencimento'   => FormatarDataUS($this->input->post('data_vencimento')),               
        );

        $query = $this->financeiro_model->set_GerarCobrancas($data);

    }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public function set_GerarCobrancas($data){

    $consulta = $this->db
            ->where('rota_cobranca', $data['rota_cobranca'])
            ->where('vinculo', 'A')
            ->get('tb_clientes')->result();


    // Com base nisso, faço o laço de repetição, para que eu insira no banco de dados, todos os boletos gerados com grupo = 10
    foreach($consulta as $valor){

        $boleto['codigo-boleto'] = ''; //AUTO_INCREMENT
        $boleto['codigo_cliente'] = $valor->matricula;
        $boleto['nosso_numero'] = '0'; //SEMPRE SERÁ "0"
        $boleto['mes_referencia'] = $data['mes_referencia']; 
        $boleto['data_emissao'] = $data['data_emissao']; 
        $boleto['data_vencimento'] = $data['data_vencimento']; 
        $boleto['data_pagamento'] = "0000-00-00"; //SEMPRE SERÁ 0000-00-00
        $boleto['valor'] = $valor->mensalidade;
        $boleto['valor_pago'] = 0; //SEMPRE SERÁ "0"
        $boleto['situacao'] = 0; //SEMPRE SERÁ "0"
        $boleto['rota_cobranca'] = $valor->rota_cobranca;
        $this->db->insert('tb_historico_financeiro', $boleto);
    }

    return;
}
```